# web container options for war file in CentOS 7

Tags: centos, java, apache-httpd

I know that `Tomcat` and `NginX` are both able to host web applications that are defined by war files.  But can `httpd` also host a war-file-based web application on a `CentOS 7` server?  If so, how would you set that up?  Where would you put the war file?  Are there security reasons to choose one container over the other? etc.

Comment: I was going to say you're wrong about nginx, but it does seem like there's a plugin that somewhat does allow java to run "in" nginx: http://wiki.nginx.org/JavaServers. That said, if you have a war file, you need a java application server to run it.

Asking high level general questions is going to be a slow process.  If you show what you've done so far and ask specific questions when stuck, that will fit better with the stackoverflow format.

As a start, can you install a web server (I would pick apache) and get www.mydomain.com/hello.html to show a web page?

Comment: @IanMcGowan Thank you for looking into this. I guess the short version of the question is (on `CentOS 7`) can I run `servlets` (a `war` file) via `httpd` or do I need `tomcat`? I have web content running through `httpd`. I also deployed a `war` to `tomcat` on the same server. I am reading intently about `tomcat` security. I would read about `httpd` security if it could run `servlets`/`wars`, or if `httpd` is necessary to run alongside `tomcat`. If `httpd` cannot run `servlets`/`wars` and is not necessary alongside tomcat, I would just delete `httpd` from the server.  All this is high level.

Comment: You need a java app server to run a java app packaged in a war file.  You should keep apache, and proxy the requests to the tomcat server (for many reasons, but to be lazy, let's just say 'best practices').

http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99434/running-apache-with-tomcat?rq=1
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21636/virtual-hosting-a-tomcat-webapp-in-apache-on-rhel-5-0

Comment: @IanMcGowan I see that you are a banker. I need to lock down a CentOS web server as tightly as Fort Knox.  Can you please point me to some resources for learning banking-grade linux web server security?